# Подскажите, пожалуйста, где должны быть запятые

Tags: пунктуация, сложное-предложение

Прошу проверить: если не хватает запятых, то поправьте меня.

*1. Даже если есть разочарования в жизни, не стоит все бросать на полпути.

2. Даже если ты сейчас один, всегда будут те, кто поддержит тебя.

3. Ты любим, и всегда им будешь, просто знай это.*

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, пожалуйста, отметьте его [как принятый](/help/accepted-answer) (галочка рядом с ответом) и поставьте ему значок ▲.

Answer (score 2):

Редактирование: **Ты любим и всегда будешь любимым, просто знай это.**

В заданном примере местоимение  ***им*** непонятно к чему относится. В первой части назван признак, но нет предмета.

Comment: Вариант с *им* не просто непонятен, он ошибочен (неверное согласование). Не так ли?

Comment: Вы правы, лучше его назвать ошибочным.

Comment: "Им" — "любимым" нельзя подразумевать?

Answer (score 1):

Как всегда, запятых не не хватает, а есть одна лишняя. Не нужна первая запятая в 3-м примере, потому что есть одно подлежащее *ты*, общее для обоих сказуемых.